# VSCode extension variable name autocomplete

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am using the autocomplete example from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/completions-sample) using JavaScript (small changes from TS to JS) and it works, but it completely replaces the default intellisense suggestions. By default it suggests words that have previously been typed.

My question is, can I either access variable names from within my extension to suggest them myself or somehow allow both my extension and the default suggestions to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, regarding access to variable names, you have no access to information about the document structure or completion items generated outside your extension. You would have to parse the document and generate according completion items yourself.

Second, regarding default suggestions, see the answer to this question: [add completionitemprovider and keep suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67272169/add-completionitemprovider-and-keep-suggestions).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yeah I figured I would just search the document for variable names myself. Regarding the score, I actually dont want to lower my score to show default word based suggestions (I can search the document myself, as stated above) but actually would rather like to increase my score. The link you provided tells me how to lower it, do you know how I could actually increase it? My specific problem is, that another extension is basically just blocking some of my extensions autocomplete suggestions.

Comment: No, unfortunately I have no idea how to _increase_ the score. I think this is exactly the issue discussed here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/21611.